# PHP form to multiple recipients

Tags: php, forms, email

I found and copied this code for sending an email via a form fill and it works, but I don't know anything about PHP coding.

I thought that I could add multiple addresses like ... $email_to: = "email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com"; ... but this only sends to the last one in the list.

I know it seem simple to you guys, but I am not able to decipher the other posts about this subject, since the other code samples are not exactly like mine, and I know nothing about how the code works.

````
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED 
    $email_to = "email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Someone registered on website.com";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['cell_phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['text_me'])){
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $cell_phone = $_POST['cell_phone']; // required
    $text_me = $_POST['text_me']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($cell_phone) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Please enter your cell phone number.<br />';
  }
    if(strlen($text_me) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Please choose whether we can text you or not.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Cell Phone: ".clean_string($cell_phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Text Me?: ".clean_string($text_me)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>```
... Please tell me what I can do to make it send to multiple emails. 
Thanks in advance!

Dan
````

Comment: Emails need to be seperated by `;` not `,`

Comment: Not according to the docs - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: `'From: '.$email_from` - **don’t**. This will increase the risk that this will get classified as spam massively. Send as an account you are allowed to send emails for (from the same domain as where this script runs, or whatever is allowed by SPF etc.), and put the user’s address in Reply-To, so that the recipient can _answer_ directly to the correct address if they like.

Comment: You do appear to be missing the closing bracket `}` at the end of your script. Is this is copy/paste error? The final `mail(...` call needs to be inside main if-statement.

Comment: Waterloomatt, I placed a "}" just before the "?>" and it broke the page = error 500.

Comment: Misorude, should I write it like this ...

Comment: ```// create email headers

$headers = 'From: 'email1@email.com"\r\n".

'Reply-To: 'email1@email.com"\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);```